Custom linux driver reboots on detach
I wrote a Linux kernel driver (DRM) for USB based screen(VoCore). When unplugging device, computer reboots without any error output. Why and how to fix it?
driver's header:
...

struct mpro_device {
    struct drm_device dev;
    struct device *dmadev;

    /* simplefb settings */
    struct drm_display_mode mode;
    const struct drm_format_info *format;
    unsigned int pitch; // pixels on line!!

    /* memory management */
    struct iosys_map screen_base;
    unsigned char* data;
    unsigned int block_size;

    /* modesetting */
    uint32_t formats[8];
    struct drm_plane primary_plane;
    struct drm_crtc crtc;
    struct drm_encoder encoder;
    struct drm_connector connector;

    /* device info */
    unsigned int screen;
    unsigned int version;
    unsigned char id[8];
    struct mpro_info info;
    struct mpro_config config;

    unsigned char cmd[64];
};

#endif /* _MPRO_H_ */

main driver code:
...

static struct mpro_device *mpro_device_create(struct drm_driver *drv, struct usb_interface *interface) {

    struct mpro_device *mpro;
    struct drm_device *dev;
    int ret;

    mpro = devm_drm_dev_alloc(&interface -> dev, drv, struct mpro_device, dev);
    if ( IS_ERR(mpro))
        return ERR_CAST(mpro);
    dev = &mpro -> dev;

    /* Config */
    mpro -> config.flipx = flipx == 0 ? 0 : 1;
    mpro -> config.partial = partial == 0 ? 0 : 1;

    /* Hardware setup */
    mpro -> dmadev = usb_intf_get_dma_device(to_usb_interface(dev -> dev));
    if ( !mpro -> dmadev )
        drm_warn(dev, "buffer sharing not supported"); /* not an error */

    ret = mpro_mode(mpro);
    if ( ret )
        return ERR_PTR(ret);

    if ( mpro -> config.flipx )
        drm_info(dev, "image flip on x axis is enabled");

    if ( mpro -> config.partial > 0 )
        drm_info(dev, "partial frame updates enabled");

    /* Memory management */
    ret = mpro_data_alloc(mpro);
    if ( ret )
        return ERR_PTR(ret);

    iosys_map_set_vaddr(&mpro -> screen_base, mpro -> data);
    if ( iosys_map_is_null(&mpro -> screen_base)) {
        drm_err(dev, "failed to allocate buffer");
        return ERR_CAST(mpro);
    }

    /* Modesetting */
    ret = mpro_modeset(mpro);
    if ( ret )
        return ERR_PTR(ret);

    /* Primary plane */
    ret = mpro_init_planes(mpro);
    if (ret)
        return ERR_PTR(ret);

    /* CRTC, Encoder, Connector */
    ret = mpro_init_connector(mpro);
    if (ret)
        return ERR_PTR(ret);

    drm_mode_config_reset(dev);

    return mpro;
}

DEFINE_DRM_GEM_FOPS(mpro_fops);

static struct drm_driver mpro_driver = {
    DRM_GEM_SHMEM_DRIVER_OPS,
    .name           = DRIVER_NAME,
    .desc           = DRIVER_DESC,
    .date           = DRIVER_DATE,
    .major          = DRIVER_MAJOR,
    .minor          = DRIVER_MINOR,
    .driver_features    = DRIVER_ATOMIC | DRIVER_GEM | DRIVER_MODESET,
    .fops           = &mpro_fops,
};

static int mpro_probe(struct usb_interface* interface, const struct usb_device_id* id) {

    struct mpro_device *mpro;
    struct drm_device *dev;
    int ret;

    mpro = mpro_device_create(&mpro_driver, interface);
    if ( IS_ERR(mpro))
        return PTR_ERR(mpro);

    ret = mpro_init_sysfs(mpro);
    if ( ret )
        drm_warn(dev, "failed to add sysfs entries");

    return mpro_fbdev_setup(mpro, MPRO_BPP);
}

static void mpro_remove(struct usb_interface *interface) {

    struct drm_device *dev = usb_get_intfdata(interface);
    struct mpro_device *mpro = to_mpro(dev);

    drm_dev_unplug(dev);
    drm_dev_unregister(dev);
    drm_atomic_helper_shutdown(dev);
    put_device(mpro -> dmadev);
    mpro -> dmadev = NULL;
}

...
MODULE_LICENSE("Dual MIT/GPL");

Driver works perfectly, tested with kmscube and Weston. But when I unplug the device, whole computer reboots; I am sure problem is in drm related part, as usb stuff is pretty straight forward.
This is minimized source, and full driver is based on simpledrm driver - which isn't for a hot pluggable device at all.
Full source code is available here: https://github.com/oskarirauta/mpro

Not sure why you have reposted the same question again. On Stack Overflow we expect the code to be in the question post itself (in form of [mcve]).

I would had added the code... If it wouldn't be separated to multiple files containing more than 1200 lines.. And I do not know in which part the problem is, because driver initialisation is not it - it is identical to many other drivers and previous versions of this same driver. Previous driver used simple pipes, this is more advanced. Surely you do not want me to include all those 1200 lines here.. It is also easier to read, or find parts of it as it's sectioned.. To reproduce the problem; you would need this pretty rare device (purchasable though). Issue is somewhere in my code.. But where?

No, I do not want you to include all those 1200 lines here. The thing is that Stack Overflow is a library of Questions/Answers. A person who faces some problem could search a question which describes the similar problem, and among answers to that question find a solution for his/her problem. For that reason a question about some code, which is not included into the question post, is not useful here.

Maybe it can be quoted when the problem is found? I did search for this problem, maybe not with correct pattern if the answer already exists, and I didn't limit my search to stack overflow- My thoughts is that it has something to do with device being hot pluggable/removable and would need special attention regarding on that; unfortunately removable gpu's are not very common; so I didn't find a proper example that I could compare; but to stay on topic.. Do you possibly have a clue for me on this?

Perhaps create a [mre]. The work of doing this often leads to solving the problem.

How? If I narrow it down, let's say; I'd remove plane and crtc related setup, it won't work at all as it's crucial that it is there - what if problem is there. If I just make it a usb driver without drm part, let's say, a hid device.. it works. Problem is inside drm part. It is based on this: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.6.30/source/drivers/gpu/drm/tiny/simpledrm.c - it is not any shorter. Difference just is that simpledrm driver isn't for hot pluggable device like mine is.

If you configure your systemd to store persistent kernel dmesgs, then what do you see after the next reboot?  There should be some evidence left behind.

systemd? I don't have it... On any of my hosts.. This host is running openwrt..
